# Show only one Ajax Indicator in a Page with a lot of them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I have a lot of Ajax indicators in a Page. Now I use

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#ajaxBusyIndicator_<%=partido.PartidoId.ToString()%>').css({ display: "inline" });
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#ajaxBusyIndicator_<%=partido.PartidoId.ToString()%>').hide();
});
```

The problem with this is that I get all the indicators to show Any way to Show only one?

**I use asp.net MVC**

UPDATE: The Problem is how in the $(document).ajaxStart(function() { know what indicator to show

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Looking at the code it seems that you're only manipulating one ajax indicator - based on some unique ID. Unless, of course, you have more than one element with the same ID on the page, which is technically incorrect.

Comment: The Problem is how in the $(document).ajaxStart(function() { know what indicator to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Asp.net MVC, you should use the AjaxOptions object to specify functions that will be called when you request initiates/completes/succeeds/fails. Inside those functions you can show/hide your indicator.

We do it like this (enabling/disabling the "loading" indicator using OnBegin/OnComplete):

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(..., new AjaxOptions { ..., 
    UpdateTargetId = 'blabla', 
    OnBegin = "msg_activate", 
    OnComplete = "msg_hide", 
    OnSuccess = "funcOnSuccess", 
    OnFailure = "funcOnFailure" })
%>
```

Then inside your msg_activate/msg_hide you can have something like this:

```
function msg_activate(response) { 
    $('#ajaxBusyIndicator_<%=partido.PartidoId.ToString()%>').css({ display: "inline" });
}

function msg_hide() {
    $('#ajaxBusyIndicator_<%=partido.PartidoId.ToString()%>').hide();
}
```

EDIT: You can do it with jQuery as well, but only if you're doing an [ajax request with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options). In this case you can use **beforeSend**, **complete**, **success**, and **error** options. Just look at the [examples](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#examples).

Comment: Any way of doing this with Jquery?

Comment: Edited to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the jquery ajaxStart event is raised for every ajax request made on that page. What your code is doing is attach several event handlers to the same event, and for each ajax request, all handlers are called.

I think you have to handle those events yourself, you can't use ajaStart for them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that will run on multiple items is if you have multiple items with the same id.

Is it possible that your "<%=partido.PartidoId.ToString()%>" is not being turned into the right id, and is instead being interpretted literally?

If you could post either a link, or some code to help us know what's happening, that would be helpfull.

Comment: The Problem is how in the $(document).ajaxStart(function() { know what indicator to show

Comment: let me just read out what I think your code will do:
when any ajax call starts, the element with the id of "ajaxBusyIndicator_<%=partido.PartidoId.ToString()%>" will become display: inline;.

When an ajax call stops, the element with the id if "ajaxBusyIndicator_<%=partido.PartidoId.ToString()%>" will become display: none; (hidden).

Have you tried using that same id to select those divs in another fashion? Have you tried selecting it with one literal value, instead of a variable?

Again, if you had an example page or some code to show.